# Как центрировать синий блок по вертикали?

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 700px;
}

.side_block_1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.between_block {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto 120px;
}
.side_block_2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side_block_1">
    
  </div>
  <div class="between_block">
    
  </div>
  <div class="side_block_2">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно заставить синий блок встать по вертикали по центру по вертикали между двумя зелеными блоками, как это можно сделать? Пробовал различные способы, пробовал `vertical-align: middle;`, но 
это ни к чему не привело меня. Абсолютное позиционирование не подходит, так как потом будут проблемы с адаптивностью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Первый вариант** с использованием `display: flex`:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.side_block_1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.between_block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto 120px;
}

.side_block_2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side_block_1">

  </div>
  <div class="between_block">

  </div>
  <div class="side_block_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Второй вариант** с использованием `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 700px;
}

.side_block_1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.between_block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.side_block_2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side_block_1">

  </div>
  <div class="between_block">

  </div>
  <div class="side_block_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если, скажем, важна кроссбраузерность?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, имеете ввиду IE 6-9?

Comment: Да, на всякий случай

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, добавил второй вариант

Answer (score -1):

Можно сократить css, ведь в классах .side_block_1 и .side_block_2 прописаны одинаковые свойства, зачем дублировать код, создай общий класс для этих двух блоков...и вот вариант, когда неизвестна высота родительского блока и самого элемента

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side_block">

  </div>
  <div class="between_block">

  </div>
  <div class="side_block">

  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 700px;
}
.side_block {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
.between_block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```